# Plotting the results from Solve in a Manipulate expression

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, manipulate

I am a self-taught Mathematica user, trying to make some progress. 
This is my code:

```
Manipulate[
  Solve[
    {(p1 a1 + p2 .2) (1 + r) + w 1 == p1, (p1 .1 + p2 .4) (1 + r) + w 30 == p2}, 
    {p1, p2}], 
  {r, 0, .45}, 
  {a1, 0, .6}]
```

I can get the manipulate-sliders for `r` and `a1`. However, I haven´t been able to integrate the plot and the manipulate functions/commands in order to get a two-dimensional plot for `p1` and `p2` (y-axis) as a function of `r` (x-axis) while manipulating the values of `a1`.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined w, so I give it an arbitrary value:

```
w = 1; 
Manipulate[
  sol = {p1, p2} /. 
       Solve[{(p1 a1 + p2 .2) (1 + r) + w 1 == p1, 
              (p1 .1 + p2 .4) (1 + r) + w 30 == p2}, {p1, p2}];
  Plot[sol, {r, 0, 045}], 
  {a1, 0, .6}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sir, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are feeding `Solve` has a unique solution and it would be most efficient to solve it once and then feed the result into `Manipulate`.

```
Solve[
 {
  (p1 a1 + p2/5) (1 + r) + w == p1,
  (p1/10 + 2 p2/5) (1 + r) + 30 w == p2},
 {p1, p2}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To simplify the code a bit it is proposed that functions representing `p1` and `p2` should be defined.

```
f1[w_, a_, r_] := (10 (33 w + 28 r w))/
   (29 - 30 a - 22 r - 10 a r - r^2 + 20 a r^2)

f2[w_, a_, r_] := -((5 (-301 w + 300 a w - r w + 300 a r w))/
  (29 - 30 a - 22 r - 10 a r - r^2 + 20 a r^2))
```

Use these in `Manipulate` with `a` and `w` as variables.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f1[w, a, r], f2[w, a, r]},
  {r, 0, 45},
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}
  ],
 {{w, 1}, 0.5, 5, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{a, 0.1}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sir, thank for your answer!