# Plotting a=f(b) and b=g(a) on the (a,b) plane when neither has a closed solution

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I've searched for a solution but haven't found one yet, but this is possibly an easy fix - I'm new to Mathematica.
I have two functions, each with $(a,b)$ as arguments and both with no closed form expression. One is a condition on $a$, "given $b$", and the other is a condition on $b$, "given $a$".
$$
(1)\quad \frac{ S a^{\delta -1} b^{\delta }}{\left(a^{\delta }+b^{\delta
   }\right)^2}=1, \quad (2) \quad  \frac{Sa^{\delta } b^{\delta -1}}{\left(a^{\delta }+b^{\delta
   }\right)^2}=1
$$
I'm trying to plot both on a single plane, by using manipulate for S. Thanks to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118835/plotting-the-results-from-solve-in-a-manipulate-expression?newreg=2637f84dbe8541109b9ebd91b68f6cb2) I am able to plot one of the equations (eq. $(1)$ which maps $b \rightarrow a$), by using Solve. This is my code.

```
\[Delta] = 1
line1 = Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 2}}]
Manipulate[ sol = a /.
   Solve[(
     a^(-1 + \[Delta])
       b^\[Delta] S \[Delta])/(a^\[Delta] + b^\[Delta])^2 == 1, a];
 Plot[sol, {b, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, 
  Epilog -> {line1}], {S, 0, 2} , {\[Delta], 0, 2}]
```

The result is exactly what I would expect based on my own algebra and sketching skills.
[image]
Now I need to add the second equation, which maps $a \rightarrow b$. I tried following the instructions in the question above, making `sol={a,b}` and solving two equations, one for $a$ and one for $b$, but it did not work. I'm guessing that has to do with $b$ being the "x-axis" for the Plot function...

```
Manipulate[ sol = {a, b} /.
   Solve[{(
      a^(-1 + \[Delta])
        b^\[Delta] S \[Delta])/(a^\[Delta] + b^\[Delta])^2 == 1, (
     b^(-1 + \[Delta])
       a^\[Delta] S \[Delta])/(a^\[Delta] + b^\[Delta])^2}, {a, b}];
 Plot[sol, {b, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {b, a}, Epilog -> {line1}], {S, 0, 2} ]
```

Seeing as the equations are symmetric I thought maybe I could [graphically transpose them](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/how-can-i-transpose-x-and-y-axis-on-a-plot). But I couldn't get it to work (with both lines on the same plot.) I'd also like to learn a general solution, for the future..

Hopefully this is clear, and thanks for any help.

Comment: You can just use `ContourPlot` to plot implicit equations directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wxffles stated ContourPlot solves your problem. By the way, the second equation in your question is incomlete...):

```
Manipulate[
ContourPlot[{(a^(-1 + \[Delta]) b^\[Delta] S \[Delta])/(a^\[Delta] +b^\[Delta])^2 == 1, 
(b^(-1 + \[Delta]) a^\[Delta] S \[Delta])/(a^\[Delta] +b^\[Delta])^2 == 1}, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}], {{S, 1}, 0, 2,ppearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly.